# ThreadLocal with Tomcat

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot, tomcat

I have a context class with ThreadLocal variable that I wanna use to store data.

**LDAPAttributesContextHolder**

```
public class LDAPAttributesContextHolder {

    private static final ThreadLocal<List<Attributes>> threadLocalScope = new ThreadLocal<>();

    private LDAPAttributesContextHolder() {
        throw new IllegalStateException("ThreadLocal context class");
    }

    public static final List<Attributes> getAttributes() {
        return threadLocalScope.get();
    }

    public static final void setAttributes(List<Attributes> attributes) {
        threadLocalScope.set(attributes);
    }

    public static final void destroy() {
        threadLocalScope.remove();
    }
}
```

I use this class to store user attributes and use it in another service.

**Service1**

```
@Override
    public boolean searchInLDAP(String userName, String email) {
        LOG.debug("Current thread is {}", Thread.currentThread().getName());
        LOG.debug("Start search user with login {} and email {} in LDAP directory", userName, email);
        List<Attributes> attributeList = new ArrayList<>();
        if(isEmpty(LDAPAttributesContextHolder.getAttributes())) {
            attributeList = ldapTemplate.search(query().base("ou=people").where("uid").is(userName).and("mail").is(email),
                    (AttributesMapper<Attributes>) attributes -> {
                        if(attributes == null) {
                            return null;
                        }
                        return attributes;
                    });
            LDAPAttributesContextHolder.setAttributes(attributeList);
        }
        LOG.debug("Status of searching user with login {} and email {} in LDAP is {}", userName, email, (!isEmpty(attributeList)) ? "success" : "failed");
        if(nonNull(attributeList) && !isEmpty(attributeList)) {
            logAttributes(userName);
        }
        return nonNull(attributeList) && !isEmpty(attributeList);
    }
```

**Serivice2**

```
public List<String> getAllFacultyGroupNamesByFacultyName() {
        String studentFacultyName = "";
        LOG.debug("Current thread is {}", Thread.currentThread().getName());
        LOG.debug("LDAPContextHolder size {}", LDAPAttributesContextHolder.getAttributes().size());
        List<Attributes> attributeList = LDAPAttributesContextHolder.getAttributes();
        LOG.debug("In method {} ,Size of attributes is  {}", Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[0].getMethodName(), attributeList.size());
        for(Attributes attributes : attributeList) {
            try {
                if(attributes.get(FACULTY_ATTRIBUTE) != null &&
                        attributes.get(ROLE_ATTRIBUTE) != null &&
                        !attributes.get(ROLE_ATTRIBUTE).get().toString().equals(ORGANIZATIONAL_PERSON)
                ) {
                    studentFacultyName = attributes.get(FACULTY_ATTRIBUTE).get().toString();
                    studentFacultyName = studentFacultyName.contains(IT_FACULTY.toLowerCase()) ? IT_FACULTY : studentFacultyName;
                    LOG.debug("Student faculty is {}", studentFacultyName);
                }
            } catch(NamingException e) {
                LOG.error("Error while parsing LDAP attributes. {}", e);
            }
        }

        return ...;
    }
```

The problem is that in the first method thread is 120, but in second for some reason thread is 115 and when I try to get context it throws NullPointer.
What did I miss?

Comment: These 2 methods are executed in different threads, so TL will not work

Comment: @rkosegi Ohh, how to catch it?

Comment: How to catch what? Why did you even expect the methods to be called by the same thread, if they are being called as part of processing different requests?

Answer (score 0):

`ThreadLocal` holds a reference [per thread](https://www.baeldung.com/java-threadlocal). So unless it is initialized per thread, you'll get null pointer exceptions. From the Javadoc:

> These variables differ from their normal counterparts in that each thread that accesses one (via its `get` or `set` method) has its own, independently initialized copy of the variable.

Sounds like you want the singleton pattern. Since you're using Spring Boot, you could create a bean of type `LDAPAttributesContextHolder` and autowire it into the components/services where it us used.

Comment: is such an approach guarantee that 5 users at this moment get only their context?

Comment: Probably not as written. If `LDAPAttributesContextHolder` is meant to be per-user, then you'd probably want some wrapper class around it which maps some sort of user ID to their context. That wrapper class then becomes the spring bean that you would autowire.

Comment: Maybe `@Scope(scopeName = "websocket", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)` can solve it?

Comment: Hard to say with the limited info we have, I would try it and see. In general a non-singleton bean might make sense, it's just a matter of scoping it for the intended user potentially across multiple requests.